# Remina not working on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xfce, rdp, remmina

I am trying to connect to a variety of linux servers using Ubuntu 20.04 Remina.
However I get the message reconnection attempt 1 of 20.

On the  remote side the xrdp logs are the following:

```
[20200831-16:56:16] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 15 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:16] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 12 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:17] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:18] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 13 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:18] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 9 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:18] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 11 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:19] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 12 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:19] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 14 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:20] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:20] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 9 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:21] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 11 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:21] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 13 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:21] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 15 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:22] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 12 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:23] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 7 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:23] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 9 started successfully
[20200831-16:56:23] [INFO ] scp thread on sck 11 started successfully
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that it was  an issue with FreeRDP.
Connection -> Edit -> Advanced:

- Relax Order Checks
- Glyph Cache
  [image]

credits: https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/issues/2163